# i need to split the merged data of 'IDDate' column, to respective columns of id and date

Tags: python, pandas

```py
row1 = ['Name1','1000','WCC126453-Mar-2022']
row2=['Name2','15000','WCC127455-Mar-2022']
row3=['Name3','20000','WCC153456-Mar-2022']
row_data=[row1,row2,row3]


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Amount','IDDate'],data=row_data)

#output
Name    Amount  IDDate
0   Name1   1000    WCC126453-Mar-2022
1   Name2   15000   WCC127455-Mar-2022
2   Name3   20000   WCC153456-Mar-2022
```

as shown here, data is merged in IDDate column where the 1st 8 digits are employee id, followed by date. i want it be separated into respective columns of these merged data(ID and Date).
i want a for loop to be added in code, so that i can perform the operation for numerous rows of my data frame.
[here is the excel data of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rs0t.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have edited and made the post clear of what i need out of it